# Как ссылку на сайте открыть в приложении андроид?

Tags: javascript, android, html5

Коллеги, на сайте есть обычная ссылка...

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a>
```

И естественно, при клике по ней я перейду по данной ссылке.

Вопрос - А если на сайт зашли с тел или планшета, как реализовать открытие той или иной ссылки не в браузере, а в приложении для `Android` или `i_OS`?

Дополню вопрос некоторыми данными. Сервер `NodeJs`, сам сайт построен на `angular-1`

Answer (score -1):

Для этого приложение на Android должно декларировать в своем манифесте способность обрабатывать соответствующий URL, типа:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />            
  <data android:scheme="http"/>
  <data android:scheme="https"/>
  <data android:host="www.youtube.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Благодарю, за ответ. Но есть большая просьба. Не имею представления, что это и куда его сунуть...

Comment: Будь другом поподробнее... Или же подскажи, что почитать...

Comment: Но это жесть... Манифест приложения под Android - это самые азы... Возьмите любой мануал по Андроид разработке - в первой же странице вы увидите что это за зверь и с чем его едят. Можно начать например [отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/index.php)

Comment: ЖЕСТЬ, то что владею только  `html css && js`? ))))))))

Comment: Ну да это жесть. Ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь решить проблему на стороне клиента Android средствами на стороне сервера. Априори ведь неизвестно какое приложение стоит у клиента, каждое приложение клиента декларирует свои возможности через манифест, условно говоря: смотри, что я умею. Если умельцев несколько и отсутствует дефолтный умелец, то клиент выставляет диалог - типа выбери умельца. А пытаться назначить со стороны сервера умельца - это бесполезно.

Answer (score -1):

Начиная с Anroid 6 (23 апи) появился механизм [deeplink](https://medium.com/@muratcanbur/intro-to-deep-linking-on-android-1b9fe9e38abd). На ранних версиях такой возможности нет, к сожалению. На ios также существует такой механизм, но об этом лучше спросить в ios треде.